# Azure Application gateway for web app

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service, internal-load-balancer, azure-traffic-manager

coming from this link
http://azureblogger.com/2016/02/load-balancing-in-azure/

Does azure application gateway support web apps? based on the above link, it says no, but i could not find it mentioned explicitely in azure documentation for app gateway.

Second question related, Is it wise/suggested to use application gateway/traffic manager for azure web app which is already scalable based on performance and currently has 2 or more instances running in standard tier.

Does using application gateway/traffic manager makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering web apps already allows you to set cookie based session affinity, I would assume they already using a Level 7 Load Balancing solution. Based on the headers you have to set to enable this, I would assume they are using this http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing. So using application gateway wouldn't make much sense.

Traffic manager has a different goal, it routes traffic on more of a global scale using DNS. For example a user in Europe will get routed to the European Azure Website, an American user will get routed to the American Azure Website. It also has automatic failover, so if a whole site fails, it get routed to a different site in a different datacentre. It also has a lot of other features for A/B testing etc. So it may make sense to use this, based on your requirements. You usually combine Traffic Manager with Load Balancers/Application Gateway by pointing traffic manager to the load balanced endpoints.